# Check string for multiple occurrence of character in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing

How can I check if a string consists only of (multiple) dashes? `'-'`, `'--'`, `'---'`, and so on need to be `True`, but e.g. `'-3'`, `'foo--'`, and the like need to be `False`. What is the best way to check for that?

Comment: Count them and compare it to the length?

Comment: It's the same as the duplicate, just change the checks where it does `my_list[0]` to whatever character you want eg `'-'`. As you can see all the answers here are the same as the dupe thread

Comment: Thanks. However the code from the link returns for this list `['---', '-', '--', 'asd-', '--asd', '']` `True, True, True, False, False, True` instead of the desired `True, True, True, False, False, False` and I'm not quite sure why - obviously because if the empty string, but how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a set.

```
>>> a = '---'
>>> len(set(a)) == 1 and a[0] == '-'
True
>>> a = '-x-'
>>> len(set(a)) == 1 and a[0] == '-'
False
```

If the length of the `set` is `1` there is only one distinct character in the string. Now we just have to check if this character is a `'-'`.

An easier way would be to compare sets.

```
>>> set('----') == set('-')
True
>>> set('--x') == set('-')
False
```

Comment: The latter seems rather elegant and works even for empty strings, unlike the example given in the 'duplicate', which hence is not really one.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways, but I think the most straighforward one is:

```
all(i == '-' for i in '----')
```

Comment: you need to change `'----'` to the name of variable

Comment: `all([]) is True` i.e., empty string might require a special handling

Answer (score 3):

You can use the builtin function [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> a= '---'
>>> all(i == '-' for i in a)
True
>>> b="----c"
>>> all(i == '-' for i in b)
False
```

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious ways are:

- Is the string equal to the string it would be if it were all dashes: `s == '-' * len(s)`;
- Does the string contain as many dashes as its length: `s.count('-') == len(s)`;
- Is the `set` of the string just a dash: `set(s) == set('-')`;
- Does the string match a regular expression for only dashes: `re.match(r'^-+$', s)`; and
- Are `all` the characters in the string dashes: `all(c == '-' for c in s)`.

There are no doubt other options; in terms of *"best"*, you would have to define your criteria. Also, what should an empty string `""` result in? All of the no characters in it are dashes...

Comment: upvote for `s.count('-') == len(s)`

Answer (score 1):

[**Using `re.match` function**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)

```
>>> import re
>>> def check(str):
...     if re.match(r"-+$", str):
...             return True
...     return False
...
>>> check ("--")
True
>>> check ("foo--")
False
```

**OR**

Shorter

```
>>> def check(str):
...     return bool ( re.match(r"-+$", str))
```

Comment: You're missing an anchor for the end of the string. `check('-x')` will return `True` with your code. Use `r"-+$"` instead.

Comment: you could use `return bool(re.match("-*$", s))` (return True for an empty string like other solutions)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I didnt knew that. Thanks for the tip